# How can I show the text at the bottom of a child div using css? I have tried, but the text goes to main div

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

How can I put the text to the bottom of a particular div using css? I have tried, but the text goes to main div

```
<div id="img1" style="background-color:red;width:100%;height:100%;">

<div id="abc">
<img id="image" src="punj.jpg" alt="PUNJ icon" style="width:5%; height:15%; float:left;">
</div> 

<div id="img1" style="background-color:#B1C7E8;width:95%;height:15%; float :left;">

<h1 id="head">
University 
</h1>
</div>
```

This is code of html

Comment: While I've tried to improve your question I still have no idea what you're asking. Please describe the problem you're facing, the solution(s) you've tried and how the solution(s) failed (what did they do wrong, or not do at all)? To tidy up, and add information to, your question please use the [edit] link below the tags of your question.

Comment: And in CSS file the code is this #img1{
    position: bottom;
    

color:white;}

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the question, but it seems like you are trying to place the text under the image? If so maybe you're looking for something in jsfiddle? I x out/commented out some styles https://jsfiddle.net/d2zaep72/ 
The code needs some cleaning up. I wouldn't use inline styles and try not use so many ids in the css if possible. There is this same id "img1" with different rules/styles. I would have give it different ids/classes.

Comment: how can i show text in child div at bottom of div in css like this code of html:   <div id="img1" style="background-color:#B1C7E8;width:95%;height:15%; float :left;">

<h1 id="head">
University 
</h1>
</div>}

Comment: I would add a <p> tag for the new text. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/gds1t82b/

Comment: but it is not show at the bottom of div

Comment: Could you attach a mock up of what you'd like to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have a closing div for your last div and you're giving height and width to the image itself instead of the div holding it.  I would style the div instead of the image for what you're trying to do.

```
<div id="abc"style="width:5%; height:15%;" >
<img id="image" src="punj.jpg" alt="PUNJ icon"  float:left;>
</div> 


<div id="img1" style="background-color:#B1C7E8;width:95%;height:15%; float :left;">
</div>
<div>
<h1 id="head">
University 
</h1>
</div>

</div>
```